# Sharing views and static files between node/express.js sub apps

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

**Background:**

I have been creating a dashboard like application where major features have been sectioned out into their own sub apps. This way I can use pm2 and scale particular sub apps based on their computing requirements. Each app has it's own sub domain but to the user it appears that they are navigating through a single site. This is because they all share the same ejs templates and a majority of the same static files and mongoose schemas.

> users.domain.com ---> express app that handles user settings
>   tasks.domain.com ---> express app that handles tasks
>   ordering.domain.com ---> express app that handles ordering items

**Question:**

How can I more easily share ejs templates and static files between these sub apps so i don't have to update something x amount of times? They all have the same header and footer template and I have to update it on every app if I decide to make a change to the theme. It would be easier if I could sync these files between the apps. Is there a way I could serve them through s3?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Typically, you'd have a top level `common` folder where you could put your views, and import them from your sub apps. If this isn't tenable, you could always package them as a private library and import them as needed like any other `node_module` from your `package.json`.

Comment: Could you place them into a private node.js module and use that? Or perhaps create a separate repo for the common pieces and add to the orders as a Git submodule?

Comment: @EvanShortiss a colleague recommended git submodules. That might be a good solution.